# Differentiating an expectation of a function parameterized by a variable

Tags: probability, expected-value

Consider a random variable $X \in \mathbb{R}$.  The distribution of $X$ depends on a value $y \in \mathbb{R}$ which is not random.  Denote it $X \sim G_y$.

The same $y$ will also be used within the expectation:
$$
g(y) = \mathbb{E}_{X \sim G_y}\left(f(X + y) \right)
$$
Assume whatever smoothness, measureability, etc. required for all variables.

My question is how to differentiate this with respect to $y$.  That is,
$$
\partial_y g(y) = \partial_y \left[\mathbb{E}_{X \sim G_y}\left(f(X + y)\right)\right]
$$
Obviously, if the $G_y$ was independent of $y$ I could just move the differentiation inside the expectation given smoothness, measureability, etc.

Comment: That conditional expectation notation doesn't make sense if $y$ is not at all random. Is it just a parameter of the distribution? Or is it actually random (perhaps with a different source of randomness than in $X$ itself such as parameter uncertainty as opposed to real fluctuation)?

Comment: Yeah, ultimately it could be random, but maybe it is easier to write it it here as just a distribution which is parameterized by $y$?

Comment: @Ian If you think that would make it more clear, I can rewrite it

Comment: OK, well first off the $+y$ can be absorbed into the choice of $G_y$, so you don't need that. Otherwise this is basically just differentiating an integral with respect to a parameter. You can generally just bring the derivative inside the integration using pretty weak assumptions about the dependence of the distribution on $y$.

Comment: In particular assuming $X_y$ has a density $g(x;y)$ then you have $\partial_y \mathbb{E}[f(X_y))]=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial y} g(x;y) dx$ under mild assumptions.

Comment: So then it just requires integration by parts to complete the expression?

Comment: No, there's no integration by parts because there's no other function of $y$ to move the derivative to. You're also not integrating with respect to the same variable as the derivative is taken with respect to.

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying.  Is there a way to write the expression above more generally in terms of changes of measure or something along those lines or do you really need to work with densities?

Comment: You don't inherently need to use densities, I just don't know what the normal notation for a derivative of a measure with respect to a parameter is.